# If time slows in the presents of gravity, how does the conclusion that the universe’s expansion is accelerating account for this?

Tags: gravity, spacetime, space-expansion

I am sure there is a simple explanation for this and I’m not a physicist so hoping someone here can help answer this for me.

Time is retarded by gravitational field. Expansion in all directions results in increasing dilution of matter in space time. Does this affect measurements of rate of expansion of the universe? How do the equations account for this when calculating rate of expansion? Thanks to anyone who sheds light on this for me.

Comment: Gravitational time dilation and the universe's expansion are kind of unrelated effects. The former is due to a spatially varying gravitational potential, i.e. from the dependence of $g_{00}$ on $\mathbf{x}$. The latter is just expansion of space itself, i.e. from the dependence of $g_{ii}$ on $t$. In the full theory of general relativity, these two things are rather separate.

Comment: Though, as you would expect, measurements of expansion are corrected in plenty of ways, as demanded by general relativity. (And no, the expansion of the universe is not just a measurement error -- if that was what you were going for, nice try, but we get somebody coming in with that idea every other day.) You can find a detailed explanation of this within the first chapter or so of literally any cosmology textbook.

Comment: "*If time slows in the presents of gravity*"; "*Time is retarded by gravitational field*" - These statements are incorrect. The gravitational acceleration is caused by time moving slower, but not the other way around. Time dilation is not **caused** by the gravitational field. Time dilation **is** the gravitational field.

Comment: @knzhou "*Gravitational time dilation and the universe's expansion are kind of unrelated effects.*" - Let me play devil's advocate here :) This statement also comes from the generic Friedmann metric of (roughly speaking) $t^2-a(t)r^2$. This metric **assumes** no time dilation. This very assumption is exactly what  the OP's question challenges. You cannot use the challenged assumption as an argument against the challenge without making your logic circular. The proper argument must show why (or if) this metric is justified.

Comment: @safesphere It seemed to me that OP was just unaware the effects were separate things (i.e. that you could have one without the other). Regarding $\Lambda$CDM the answer is, no doubt, that it fits a lot of data points pretty well with only three free parameters, and there are no contenders that give as much bang for the buck.